# Number Guessing game windows forms

Tags: c#

I'm doing a number guessing game in C#, the code is supposed to count players guesses and then add the number to a textbox.

I don't really know how to implement it in my code though.

I just need help with the textbox part of the code.

The guesses are supposed to appear in `tbxMinaResultat`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form    
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int datornsTal;
    int guesses;
    int max;
    public Form1()
    {


        InitializeComponent();
        lbxStörstaTalet.Items.Add(10);
        lbxStörstaTalet.Items.Add(20);


    }

    private void BtnSpelaIgen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gbxSpeldata.Enabled = true;
        gbxSpelet.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void LbxStörstaTalet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void TbxMinaResultat_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int guesses;
        tbxMinaResultat.Text = ToString(guesses);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void BtnStartaSpelet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int max = int.Parse(lbxStörstaTalet.SelectedItem.ToString());
        datornsTal = rnd.Next(0, max);

        gbxSpeldata.Enabled = false;
        gbxSpelet.Enabled = true;
        guesses = 0;
    }

    private void BtnGissa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int guess = int.Parse(tbxGissa.Text);

        if (guess > datornsTal)
        {
            lblResultat.Text = "Gissa lägre";
            guesses++;
        }

        else if (guess < datornsTal)
        {
            lblResultat.Text = "Gissa Högre!";
            guesses++;
        }

        else if (guess == datornsTal)
        {
            lblResultat.Text = "Bra jobbat!";
            guesses++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of `BtnGissa_Click` put the guesses to a text box:

```
   ...
    //existing code
    else if (guess == datornsTal)
    {
        lblResultat.Text = "Bra jobbat!";
        guesses++;
    } 

    //add this line
    tbxMinaResultat.Text = guesses.ToString();
}
```

Couple of learning points here:

- `guesses` Is an int. `tbxMinaResultat.Text` is a string. You can't assign an int to a string without converting the int to a string first.
- there are a few ways to convert ints to strings; calling ToString is probably the most self explanatory, and it can take an optional formatting instruction.
- when you programmatically alter the string in the Text property of a text box, the value displayed in the textbox changes soon after - I say soon because the event handler code has to finish and let the framework thread that is handling the button click go back to its usual job of updating the UI. If you started an operation that took ten seconds to complete right after you set the Text, your app would appear to hang for ten seconds , then the textbox would show the new value. Always be mindful of this and don't tie up the thread that runs your event handler code for too long. Ways to keep applications responsive are out of scope for what you're learning at the moment but bear this nugget of info in mind

---

I strongly recommend you remove the event handler from tbxMinaResultat.TextChanged too:

- in the forms designer, click the tbxMinaResultat textbox,
- click the lightning icon in the properties grid,
- delete the TextChanged entry
- remove the `TbxMinaResultat_TextChanged` method from the code

It's not necessary to respond to an event raised when the text in this text box changes - you are looking to change the text, not respond to an event of something else changing the text (which is what TextChanged is for)